# Existence of connection with full holonomy

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, connections

Suppose $P$ is a $G$ principal bundle over a connected manifold $M$. I am struggling with a question: Does always exist a connection $\omega$ with holonomy being equal $G$?